# How to iterate on all properties of an object in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am new to C#, I want to write a function to iterate over properties of an object and set all null strings to "". I have heard that it is possible using something called "Reflection" but I don't know how.

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a fairly odd thing to be doing. I'm curious to know what you are trying to achieve with it ?

Comment: On a side note, you might want to consider setting your null strings to "String.Empty" instead of "". The real-world impact is negligible, but for the sake of efficient code the former doesn't create a new object.

Comment: Also, I agree with andynormancx .... what's your objective here ?

Comment: In my application there are lots of objects of different types with great number of fields that must get initialized, it takes so much time to initialize fields one by one.

Comment: Why do you need then initialised to empty strings rather than null ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        // Use reflection to get all string properties 
        // that have getters and setters
        var properties = from p in typeof(Foo).GetProperties()
                         where p.PropertyType == typeof(string) &&
                               p.CanRead &&
                               p.CanWrite
                         select p;

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = (string)property.GetValue(foo, null);
            if (value == null)
            {
                property.SetValue(foo, string.Empty, null);
            }
        }

        // at this stage foo should no longer have null string properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, checking for read/write is important before reading/writing.

Comment: I think you forgot to add a `BindingFlag` when getting properties via reflection?

Comment: @Danny, the OP didn't specify anything about the visibility of the properties he is talking about. If you omit this flags it will fetch public properties only which seems reasonable enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(PropertyInfo pi in myobject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public))
{
    if (pi.GetValue(myobject)==null)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
object myObject;

PropertyInfo[] properties = myObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332493(VS.71).aspx

Comment: from the referenced doc: "For the GetProperties(BindingFlags) overload to successfully retrieve property information, the bindingAttr argument must include at least one of BindingFlags.Instance and BindingFlags.Static, along with at least one of BindingFlags.NonPublic and BindingFlags.Public."