# initializing all string properties to some value

Tags: c#

I have some object models that contain strings. Some of these properties get populated at runtime but some don't so when I map these objects back to some database fields, some fields get stored as NULL instead of just an empty string. To get around this, I set these properties to `= "";` in the constructors. Now I've got about 30 of these string properties so that's a lot of lines that just set string properties to "". Is there a way to say

```
"at object instantiation, set all strings to = "";
```

So that I can write

```
public class MyModel : SomeSpecialTypeThatInitializesStrings {}
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate on all properties of an object in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291059/how-to-iterate-on-all-properties-of-an-object-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its good idea to handle this issue on SQL Server side setting default value for your varchar columns

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD COLUMNNAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT ''
```

Comment: That's actually a very clean way of doing what I want to do!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  I wrote a Macro parser in my project that parsed all string properties for macros in a particular object.  The idea is that you use reflection to iterate over the properties of an object, and call the `SetValue` method on the appropriate ones.

First order of the day (for me) was to create an extension method for `System.Type`:

```
public static partial class TypeExtensionMethods
{
    public static PropertyInfo[] GetPublicProperties(this Type self)
    {
        return self.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where((property) => property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && property.CanRead && property.CanWrite).ToArray();
    }   // eo GetPublicProperties
}   // eo class TypeExtensionMethods
```

And then to use it on an object (note, `ForEach` is an extension method but is just short-hand for `for each()`:

```
        obj.GetType().GetPublicProperties().ForEach((property) =>
            {
                if (property.GetGetMethod().ReturnType == typeof(string))
                {
                    string value = (string)property.GetValue(obj, null);
                    if (value == null)
                        property.SetValue(obj, string.Empty, null);
                }
            }
```

Comment: That seems a bit overkill for me but I'm sure it works; upvoted.

Comment: @frenchie, well one advantage is that you write the extension method once, and could conceivably write an extension method to then use it and populate all strings with any value you desire in any circumstance.  But yes, the SQL route is perhaps best in your case, I was going for a more generalised approach :)