# Looping through all properties from viewmodel in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Currently learning MVC. I was wondering if there was a way that I could loop through all of the variables in my ViewModel while in the controller, grabbing the `Display(Name =` and the value.

I basically have a form that sends an e-mail with the info in a table format. It would be much easier and more future-proof for me to loop through them and write variables' Display Name's and values until at the end of the model while not writing null values.

Instead, I feel like I'd have to do this for every value.

```
if (model.Name != null)
{
    sb.AppendLine("<tr><td"><strong>Name: </strong></td><td>" + model.Name + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Note: That's in the post request after the model has been validated. It's building the e-mail message.

Comment: Sure use reflection to get a list of _properties_ (not "variables"), and loop through them.

Comment: Side note - why are you appending HTML as strings instead of using Razor or other syntax?

Comment: That's me building the HTML for the MailMessage.Body in the controller's HttpPost.  The form itself is using Razor.  If there's a better way I can do that, I'm for it.  I will look into reflection.  Thanks!

Comment: Have a search in SO for "C# reflection properties", here's one that almost matches what you need except use `GetValue` instead of SetValue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291059/how-to-iterate-on-all-properties-of-an-object-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting a list of data to your view, You can try something like this using Razor:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   if(item.name!=null)
   {
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
          <td>@item.name</td>
        </tr>
   }
}
```